# Apache combining LDAP and DBD with require ldap-group

Tags: apache-2.2

Hi I want to combine LDAP and DBD auth in apache 2.2

I want to be able to express in Apache config language - 
if the user is a LDAP user then he is authorized  only if he is part of a LDAP Group. However if he is a normal user then allow him as long as he is valid.

Here is what I have right now

```papche
   AuthType basic
   AuthBasicProvider ldap dbd
   AuthDBUserPWQuery "blah blah"

   AuthLDAPURL "ldap://test.com,DC=test,DC=com/CN=users,DC=test,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"   
   AuthLDAPBindDN "testuser" 
   AuthLDAPBindPasswd "testpass"

   require valid-user
   require ldap-group "CN=something,OU=whatever,DC=test,DC=com"   
   satisfy all
```

Now if I login as a AD user who is not part of the ldap group it will still allow me to login. I am guessing this is because require valid-user kicks in and it seems to be happy with that.
If I put `AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on` then it wont allow me to login as the dbd user since it insists on checking for the ldap group. Howver ldap now works well and allows only the group users.

Answer (score 1):

Will the users that you want to auth with DBD change often? If not, you could do something similar to the following:

```
require user tom dick harry
require ldap-group "CN=something,OU=whatever,DC=test,DC=com"
satisfy any
```